# Infinite Marquee responsive no gap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with this code.
I want to apply a marquee effect to this words with continues animation.
In my result, at the 100% Keyframe, the animation return to 0 and the effect is orrible!
I want animation to be fully responsive.
Thank u very much!

With this video you can see the error -> [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVh0Taw13kD5TTMeFvdUbwR3SKl2Grlc/view?usp=sharing)

```js
var elements = $('ul.tithome li').length;

for(var i=0;i < elements; i++){
 $(".tithome").clone().prependTo( ".scorri" );
};

var liEle = [];
var liEle = $(".tithome li");
```

```css
.cont{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scorri{
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: marquee;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tithome{
  display: contents;
}

.tithome li{
  width: fit-content;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% {left: -88.79%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
<div class="scorri">
  <ul class="tithome">
    <li>Governance</li>
    <li>HR</li>
    <li>Sales</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does *without with no gap* mean? Also, your code does continuously animate. As for being fully responsive, what is your desire?

Comment: Hi Scott, sorry for my English.
the gap between the words isn't problem.
if you see the animation until the end, the words doesn't flow infinitely, but stops at a certain instant of time and starts again from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate a `transform` property instead of `left`:

```js
var elements = $('ul.tithome li').length;

for(var i=0;i < elements; i++){
 $(".tithome").clone().prependTo( ".scorri" );
};

var liEle = [];
var liEle = $(".tithome li");
```

```css
.cont{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scorri{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.tithome{
    animation-name: marquee;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tithome li{
    width: fit-content;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
<div class="scorri">
  <ul class="tithome">
    <li>Governance</li>
    <li>HR</li>
    <li>Sales</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is best marque solition, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i just saw this post. It saves my time. Thanks a lot. By the way i create a pen for this and just remove some empty spaces from list and change it to scss.

if someone needs it can find from this address

https://codepen.io/tsdln/pen/LYOLdXQ

```
var elements = $('ul.list li').length;
```